# filter list dataframe by element

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I have a list and dataframe (example below).

```
                                     0  1
0                ((test1, AA), (1, 1))  1
1                ((test2, BB), (1, 1))  2
2                ((test1, CC), (1, 1))  3
3                ((test1, DD), (2, 1))  8
4                ((test3, EE), (3, 1))  9
```

I need to filter out only data with first elements `test1` AND `1` . Could you please help?

Expected output:

```
                                     0  1
0                ((test1, AA), (1, 1))  1
2                ((test1, CC), (1, 1))  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
v =  df[0].apply(lambda i: i[0][0] == 'test1' and i[1][0] == 1)
df = df[v]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                       0  1
0  ((test1, AA), (1, 1))  1
2  ((test1, CC), (1, 1))  3
```

Comment: Solution is simplify